# C++ overloading and picking right function

Tags: c++

C++ Overloading of methods question

I have 1 parent class call Vehicle

I have 2 child class call Motorcycle and Car

I have this value call getNoOfWheels();

Parent class got that method, motorcycle and car also got.

Lets say i prompt user for input

```
string vehicleType;
cout << "What is your vehicle type" << endl;
cin >> vehicleType;
```

base on user input, how do i make the program pick the right function base on vehicleType , i know i can use if VehicleType== , but thats defeat the purpose of overloading.

was given suggestion on using virtual method earlier on. in such case

```
virtual int noOfVerticles() const { return 0; }
```

For shape.h

I have same function for Car and motorcycle, but how do i make the noOfVerticles pick the right function from the child class base on vehicleType

I tried something like this..

```
Vehicle cVehicle;
Car &rCar = &cVehicle;


if(inVehicle=="Car")
{
cout << rCar.noOfWheels() << endl;
}
```

I get an error that say..

```
invalid initizliation of non-const refenrece of type "Car&" from an rvaleu of type Vehicle*
```

and ...

this is my virtual function at Car.cpp

```
public:
virtual int noOfWheels() const { return 4; }
```

**Thanks.!**

Comment: It looks like a homework question. In that case, please add tag homework. Also, first show us what you tried, and then ask a specific question.

Comment: @sahaj The homework tag is [obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info)

Comment: I suggest reading about polymorphism.  How about this: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/polymorphism/intro/

Comment: @user1600289 If you have a *pointer* to a Vehicle and you have the code `pVehicle->noOfWheels()` then the correct virtual function will be picked *automatically*, that is how virtual functions work. If that is not working for you then you are doing something wrong, and we need to see all your code.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
Car &rCar = &cVehicle;
```

then you declare `rCar` to be a *reference* but you assign to it a *pointer*. The ampersand (`&`) does different things depending on where it's used.

When it's used in `&cVehicle` it's the *address of* operator, and returns a pointer to `cVehicle`. When used in variable declaration then it tells the compiler that the variable is a reference.

---

As for your problem, it seems that you are doing it a little wrong way around. When using virtual methods you don't have to check the type of the object, the compiler will handle it for you.

Lets say you have this declaration:

```
Vehicle *pVehicle = new Car;
```

Now the variable `pVehicle` is a pointer to the base class, but since it's assigned a pointer to the sub-class virtual functions will work anyway:

```
std::cout << "Number of wheels = " << pVehicle->noOfWheels() << '\n';
```

The above will print that the number of wheels is 4, since the compiler will automatically call the correct function. If you later change `pVehicle` to point to a `Motorcycle` instance, and do the above printout again, it will correctly say 2.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of virtual methods is for you to be able to call type specific methods by unified method call.

This is represented in memory like this (this isn't actual memory layout, just for better imagination):

```
[some class attribute]
[another class attribute]
[pointer to getNoOfWheels()]
[more class attributes]
```

When you call `noOfVerticles()` in your program, it calls whatever `[pointer to getNoOfWheels()]` is pointing to (this is opposite to what would "normal call do", which would be call to `Vehicle::getNoOfWheels()`).

When you create instance of `Vehicle`:

```
[pointer to noOfVerticles] = Vehicle::getNoOfWheels()
```

If you create `Car` or `Bike` it would be represented:

```
[pointer to noOfVerticles] = Car::getNoOfWheels()
[pointer to noOfVerticles] = Bike::getNoOfWheels()
```

Assuming you have following class hierarchy:

```
class Vehicle {
public:
    virtual int getNoOfWheels() const { return 0; } // Though this should be pure virtual method
}

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    virtual int getNoOfWheels() const { return 4; }
}

class Bike : public Vehicle {
public:
    virtual int getNoOfWheels() const { return 2; }
}
```

So suddenly this will happen:

```
Vehicle *one = new Vehicle(),
        *two = new Car(),
        *three = new Bike();

one->getNoOfWheels(); // Vehicle::getNoOfWheels() - thus 0
two->getNoOfWheels(); // Car::getNoOfWheels() - thus 4
three->getNoOfWheels(); // Bike::getNoOfWheels() - thus 2

// And you still call original method of a vehicle in car:
two.Vehicle::getNoOfWheels(); // 0
```

The only thing for you to do now is to assign right new instance to car, but that's already covered in [ForEverS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13083280/1149736).

Answer (score 0):

Try using..

```
Vehicle *vehicle1= new Car(); 

Vehicle *vehicle2= new MotorBike();
```

You can call the function `vehicle1->getNoOfWheels()` or `vehicle2->getNoOfWheels()`.
this will call the function of Car and MotorBike class. This will happen only when you declare you function as virtual in the base class vehicle.

Same is applicable to reference variable.